# How to install pthreads package on OSX PHP 5.6 using pecl?

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm using `pecl` to install **pthreads** package on OSX , PHP 5.6 but it is incorrect. `pecl` package is available (checked).

```
$ pecl install pthreads
```

Error

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pthreads" install
>   failed

```
$ pecl config-get php_dir
/usr/local/lib/php
$ php -i | grep Thread
Thread Safety => disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted in your update, you are not running a thread-safe version of PHP. This is a prerequisite for installing the pthreads extension, hence why you cannot find a release compatible for your installation of PHP.

Also note that pthreads is no longer supporting PHP 5.6 and below. Instead, you should utilise pthreads v3 targeting the PHP 7.x series to receive the latest bug fixes and features.

Comment: No. As I mentioned firstly, you *must* be using a thread-safe version of PHP in order to use pthreads. The additional note in my reply was a *recommendation*, where if you upgrade to PHP 7.x, then you will be able to use a maintained version of pthreads.